# Git: Keep file in a specific branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have an habit of keeping a TODO.txt file on the root of my repository. This brings a lot of trouble when merging two branches, since as you'd expect, there are always conflicts.

I'm trying to keep this file always pinned to the master branch. Changes to it would not be tracked unless from that branch. The file would stay when checking out other branches, but changes would only be seen in the master branch.

I'm dreaming of something like:

```
git pin TODO.txt master
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid there is not a perfect way to meet your requirement in every aspect. But you can compromise if the two ways below is ok for you:

1. You want to find TODO.txt in each branch and the history of TODO.txt is inessential for you. So you can add TODO.txt in `.gitignore` file
2. If the history of TODO.txt is important for you and it’s ok for you find only the file in master branch. You can remove for file for other branches

Comment: Thanks. However, removing the file from other branches would not suit me, as I'd like to view and edit the file from various branches. Ignoring it is not also what I look for, as I'd like to have that file versioned in the development branch.